# MongoDB: how to prevent mongod from printing textually long queries to stdout?

Tags: mongodb, stdout

In my use case, I occasionally need to retrieve many 1000s of rows by ID and use a query of the form:

> db.myCollection.find({_id:{$in:[ID1, ID2, ID3, …]})

The mongod process always dumps the text of these queries to stdout, and it appears that most of the query time is spent doing so.

I’ve tried the “--quiet” and “--diaglog 0” (oplogging off) and even the unrelated “--nojournal”, which seemed to be the only command line parameters that might control this (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters).

How can I get mongod to NOT display the text of these queries, so as to improve performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with the [Profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler). The Profiler is responsible for managing this output.

Comment: That's exactly what was needed.  In particular, I found that using a large value for "--slowms" will suppress logging of queries to stdout (e.g. "mongod --slowms=1000000").